# Displaying only one item in recycler view after adding footer view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recycerview for displaying my data.In recyclerview I am using two view holders, one for getting recycling items and another for footer layout in recycler view. Only one item in arraylist is displaying...I have tried changing conditions in getItemViewType()
Through that I am getting some cases where ,
1.Displaying one item in arraylist and footer view
2.Displaying  all items in arraylist but no footer view

```
 private static final int TYPE_FOOTER=1;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM=2;
```

This is my oncreateViewHolder,

```
 public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType==TYPE_ITEM) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.details_recycler_view_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType==TYPE_FOOTER) {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_footer_view, parent, false);
        FooterViewHolder viewHolder = new FooterViewHolder(listItem);
        return viewHolder;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

This is my onbindviewholder,
In objectArrayList I am having 2 object. But It displaying only the data present in first object.

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                if(holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
                    ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
                    AndroidLogger.log(5,TAG,"position"+position);
                    DetailsObject data = objectArrayList.get(position);
                    viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(data.name());
                    viewHolder.validTextView.setText(data.getValue());
                    viewHolder.activeButton.setText("Active");
                    viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(photo);

                }
                else if(holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
                    FooterViewHolder footerViewHolder=(FooterViewHolder) holder;
                    DetailsObject data = objectArrayList.get(position);
              if (data != null) {
                   footerViewHolder.rateTextView.setText(data.getRate() );
                   footerViewHolder.rentTextView.setText(data.getRent() );
                   footerViewHolder.billTextView.setText(data.getBill() );


               }
                }
           }
```

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objectArrayList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
         if (position==objectArrayList.size()-1)
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
```

Please Anybody look into my problem and help me to   solve this issue..I really can't able to find out the problem.I am trying to get solution for a long hours ago, till now not able to find solution.

Comment: Before asking question, i suggest you to look at what the exception meaning. You are assigning more itemCount than array length .https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: Yes I understood that but I am getting this exception  when I add a footer view. @Muhammed Yalçın Kuru

Comment: make sure that the `details_recycler_view_item` is set to wrap content and not match parent

Comment: yes.. details_recycler_item is already set to wrap content...but also only displaying one item @Daniel

Comment: Can you show your adapter's constructor, and whereever you add or pass the footer item

Comment: I checked it well there is no issues.I'm getting data correctly @AjahnCharles

Answer (score 1):

you must add footer's object to objectArrayList before passing this objectArrayList to adapter and then

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objectArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == objectArrayList.size() - 1 ? TYPE_FOOTER : TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

---

in adapter you shoud'nt leave if statement without else statement

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    DetailsObject data = objectArrayList.get(position);

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_ITEM) {
        ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        AndroidLogger.log(5, TAG, "position: " + position);
        viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(data.name());
        viewHolder.validTextView.setText(data.getValue());
        viewHolder.activeButton.setText("Active");
        viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(photo);
    } else {
        FooterViewHolder footerViewHolder=(FooterViewHolder) holder;
        if (data != null) {
            footerViewHolder.rateTextView.setVisibility(true); 
            footerViewHolder.rateTextView.setText(data.getRate());
            footerViewHolder.rentTextView.setVisibility(true);
            footerViewHolder.rentTextView.setText(data.getRent());
            footerViewHolder.billTextView.setVisibility(true);
            footerViewHolder.billTextView.setText(data.getBill());
        } else {
            AndroidLogger.log(5, TAG, "this is null in position: " + position);
            footerViewHolder.rateTextView.setVisibility(false); 
            footerViewHolder.rentTextView.setVisibility(false);
            footerViewHolder.billTextView.setVisibility(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you have said,now I am getting the layout but in recyclerview itemviewholder displaying only the first object from objectArrayList@Shahriyar Aghajani

Comment: I have an another issue and really I can't able to find a solution.I have edited my question.so please kindly look into that and help me @Shahriyar Aghajani

Comment: Instead of corrupting your list, keep the footer item separate, and just set the Recycler size to be the list size + 1 and remove the -1 from the position checks in getItemViewType and bind.

Comment: @AjahnCharles now it is displaying correctly. Thank you so much really I feel very better becoz of you. Once again thank you:-)

Comment: test this, @Kousalya